# RailsAdmin: hstore columns don't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

When trying to create, view or edit a record in [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), hstore columns don't show up. I assume RailsAdmin doesn't cater for this Postgres datatype despite it being supported natively in Rails 4.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you find a workaround / fix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way I found to add hstore fields to Rails Admin is to use the Rails 4 `store_accessor` in the model and list the fields in the Rails admin config for the model.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :modules, :internal, :external, :default => 'no'

  rails_admin do
    Organization.stored_attributes[:modules].each do |field|
      configure field
    end
  end
end
```

I made [a full demo available on Github.](https://github.com/monkbroc/RailsAdminHstore)

The demo also includes support for boolean attributes stored in a hstore field, with Rails Admin checkboxes to edit them.